# reading text file in jess rule engine

Tags: jess

I have created a script.txt file for retail ontology which is a user input file. I need to run this file using batch command in jess. When I run the following command

```
batch script.txt
```

in the jess console of protege 3.5 i get the following error.

```
Jess reported an error in routine batch
while executing (batch script.txt).
Message: Cannot open file.
Program text: ( batch script.txt )  at line 1.
Nested exception is: script.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I also tried to specify the path where the script.txt file is located but still the same error exists.

Comment: When you start Jess in directory x, is script.txt a file in this directory? The pathname in the batch command must be relative to the directory from where you have started Jess.

Comment: yes , the jess and the script.txt are in the same directory